# How do I measure the size of a boost interprocess vector in shared memory?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I'm using boost::interprocess::vector to share some strings between processes, and I want to make sure I do not overflow the shared memory segment it lives in.

How do I find how much space the vector takes in memory, and how much memory a special segment-allocated string will take?

```
typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager SegmentManager;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, SegmentManager> CharAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> ShmString;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<ShmString, SegmentManager> StringAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<ShmString, StringAllocator> ShmStringVector;

const size_t SEGMENT_SIZE = ...;

addToSharedVector(std::string localString){
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, kSharedMemorySegmentName);
    ShmStringVector *shmvector = segment.find<ShmStringVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName).first;

    size_t currentVectorSizeInShm =  ?????(shmvector);            <--------  HALP!
    size_t sizeOfNewStringInSharedMemory =   ?????(localString);  <--------

    //shared mutex not shown for clarity

    if (currentVectorSizeInShm + sizeOfNewStringInSharedMemory < SEGMENT_SIZE)  {
        CharAllocator charAllocator(segment.get_segment_manager());
        ShmString shmString(charAllocator);
        shmFunctionName = localString.c_str();
        shmvector->push_back(shmString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Quick and dirty

   You can make the shared memory a physically mapped file and see how many pages have actually been committed to disk. This gives you a rough indication on many implementations as pages are most likely committed 1 at at time, and usual memory pages sizes are 4kb.

   I have another answer<sup>**[1]**</sup> that shows you the basics of this method.
2. You can use the get_free_memory() on the segment manager. Note that this doesn't say what's allocated /just/ for that vector, but it gives you an (arguably more useful) idea of how much space is *actually* occupied.

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287171/bad-alloc-is-thrown/21287572#21287572) <sup>**[2]**</sup> I have used that to benchmark differences in memory overhead between data containers with contiguous storage vs. node-based containers.

[image]

As you can see, individual allocations have high overhead, and reallocation leads to fragmentation really quickly. So it's worth looking at

- reserving space ahead of time to prevent reallocations
- using specialized Boost Interprocess allocators to make better use of the Shared Memory area

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> *see* [Memory Mapped Files, Managed Mapped File and Offset Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991213/memory-mapped-files-managed-mapped-file-and-offset-pointer/21009839#21009839)

**<sup>[2]</sup>** *see* [Bad alloc is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287171/bad-alloc-is-thrown/21287572#21287572)

Comment: Oh, by the way, the quick & dirty method is shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21009839/85371