# Keeping fixed size symbols in shared memory

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, boost

I have been working on something which requires me store the list of symbols and the corresponding count, these are being stored as a string,int mapping. The problem is the input size is around 32 MB however when I try to store it in memory the size bloats to 1.4Gb, I went through a few links and found that std::string takes up a fair amount of memory for book keeping and is likely to cause the bloat, so I looked a little further and found that one could use the boost::array with a size equal to the max size of the symbol and since the boost array doesn't do any book keeping it doesn't cause memory bloat.
However, I wish to place this boost array in the shared memory like so `map<boost::array<char, 15>`, int>.I took a look at the boost::array documentation and found that it doesn't support allocators, currently I am using allocators and segment managers from boost as follows:

```
typedef bip::allocator<char, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> CharAllocator;
typedef bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> SharedString;
```

I also came across this link, which seems to explain a lot:
   http://jovislab.com/blog/?p=89

Is there a way to do this, what are the other choices that I have. I am not looking for complete solutions, but hints. 
   Thanks, 
   Deb!

Comment: `std::string` does _not_ inherently bloat 32MB of data to 1.4GB!!! You did something hugely wrong in your code.

Comment: _"I am not looking for complete solutions, but hints."_ This suggests that you do not mean to submit an entry to this repository of Q&As, but instead are looking for a discussion board, forum or chat room really.

Comment: Does it blow up if your using the std::allocator

Comment: @surt I have not tested with std:allocator yet, please let me try that and come back with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper hints are:

- use contiguous allocations
- reserve up front

This answer contains a good side-by-side comparison of different allocation techniques with Boost managed_shared_memory:

- [How do I measure the size of a boost interprocess vector in shared memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305868/how-do-i-measure-the-size-of-a-boost-interprocess-vector-in-shared-memory/26306053#26306053) [image]

In your particular case you could flatten the allocation by using

- `flat_map` and
- use pool allocator for the strings (or perhaps use `boost::string_ref` to refer to strings allocated from on large `std::vector<char>`)